# Can a macro expand differently if it's used in a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I would like to have a macro, say `MAGIC`, or `MAGIC(*this)` so that:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() {
    cout << MAGIC; //Prints 1
  }
  void f() {
    cout << MAGIC; //Prints 0
  }
};
```

I'm only interested in this very usage. I don't care what happens when the macro is used from some other macro. It would be nice if it also worked for non-member functions.

The macro can theoretically also expand to some template trait that would then do the real magic.

I'm using MSVC, which provides a set of macros to get the current function name as a string literal. If I could compare that literal with the class name literal, which I also assume I can have, then I could do it (assuming there are no other issues linked to name mangling and templates), but you can't pass char* literals as template arguments, so I'm afraid it's impossible to achieve this.

I know it can be done at run time by using strcmp and maybe caching the result in a local static variable, but I'd like to have it at compile time.

#### EDIT

The following works on GCC, but it's really ugly, as it destroys the syntax.
It would be nice if I could at least use the opening curly braces as the traditional C++ syntax would require.

```
constexpr bool same_str(char const* a, char const* b) {
  return *a==*b && (*a==0 || same_str(a+1, b+1));
}

template< bool bSame >
struct SSame {
  static int const value = (int)bSame;
};

#define MAGIC SSame<same_str(c_strFuncName, c_strClassName)>::value

#define DEF_CLASS(x) x { constexpr static char const* c_strClassName = #x;
#define DEF_FUNC(x, ...) x(__VA_ARGS__) { constexpr static char const* c_strFuncName = #x;

struct DEF_CLASS(Foo)
  DEF_FUNC(Foo)
    cout << MAGIC;
  }
  void DEF_FUNC(f)
    cout << MAGIC;
  }
};
```

Comment: Possibly analyze `__func__` or similar via a compile time `constexpr` function?

Comment: @Columbo Good one. MSVC doesn't support constexpr, though. I'm trying on Ideone, where I get: `error: the value of ‘__FUNCTION__’ is not usable in a constant expression`

Comment: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` should expand to a string literal.  There can be complications though... the parsing would be non-trivial, especially when considering all little side-cases.

Comment: @Columbo `constexpr` aren't known to the preprocessor.

Comment: At least for GCC, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not a macro (it's an identifier for a variable, not a literal), because as James says, the preprocessor has no idea what function a macro appears in, or even what a function is.

Comment: @Columbo More likely, it expands to the name of a `char const[]` variable.  (This is what C requires for `__func__`.)  But you never know.  Either way, it isn't usable in a preprocessor expression.

Comment: @JamesKanze I see. I always thought `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a macro - possibly because of the upper-case identifier.

Comment: @Columbo It may be a macro which expands to a string literal or the name of a static local variable, or it maybe something completely different.  The C standard _requires_ a local `static char const __func__[] = "...";`, so it seems reasonable for the macro to expand to this, or something similar.  At any rate, it's nothing whose value can be used within a macro.

Comment: @JamesKanze I never suggested to use it inside a macro, but rather as an argument to a `constexpr` function (taking `char const(&)[N]`). There is no inherent reason for that to be impossible. (BTW: You can put it inside a replacement-line or whatever. Or what did you mean by "use"?)

Comment: @Columbo `__func__` is, as JamesKanze said, a `static char const[]`, which is *not* a `constexpr`. Thus, you can't use it as an argument to a `constexpr` function, if you want it to be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.  Macros are evaluated *before* the code
is parsed, so there is no way to obtain lexical context.  As for
getting the current function name with a macro, that fails on
several counts: first, the macros which return the current function
name actually expand to the name of a compiler generated
variable which contains the name; second, there's no way
to compare strings in the macro anyway; and third, unless you
wanted to limit it to just one constructor, what name would you
compare it to anyway?

Comment: Macros are evaluated before the code is parsed, but template structures are not. The `__FUNCDNAME__` macro expands to the undecorated function name, which *is* lexical context.

Comment: The idea is that macro will provide me with string literals for the class and function name, and then a class template will give me a value depending on whether those strings are the same. I avoided stating it explicitly not to influence the answerers.

Comment: @GiulioFranco In other words, you asked a question A, but wanted an answer to a completely different question B (not that I think that there is a simple solution to your question B either).

Comment: why do you think so? I asked for a macro, without specifying what the macro should expand to (may be a template or whatever black magic works). I thought a template would be needed, but didn't clearly state that because I might just have been wrong.